# UIPrintPageRenderer and UIViewPrintFormatter

Tags: swift3, uiprintpagerenderer

Anyone able to use these APIs? I would like to know if using these APIs will make your app rejected in App Store review? I [found this answer from other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184320/3296696) its from 2015 so I'm not sure if still the case 'til now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on apple forum and one staff replied that the said API is *FINE* to use. As it's a public API. I guess the referred thread no longer the case now.